# Kettle 9.2 PDI version is throwing null pointer exception

Tags: pentaho, kettle

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.getObjectName(Database.java:4905)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject.grabLoggingObjectInformation(LoggingObject.java:146)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingObject.<init>(LoggingObject.java:57)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingRegistry.registerLoggingSource(LoggingRegistry.java:136)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LoggingRegistry.registerLoggingSource(LoggingRegistry.java:123)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.logging.LogChannel.<init>(LogChannel.java:93)
        at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:265)
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.delegates.KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.<init>(KettleDatabaseRepositoryConnectionDelegate.java:119)
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.init(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:158)
        at org.pentaho.di.repository.kdr.KettleDatabaseRepository.init(KettleDatabaseRepository.java:144)
        at org.pentaho.di.base.AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.establishRepositoryConnection(AbstractBaseCommandExecutor.java:196)
        at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.KitchenCommandExecutor.execute(KitchenCommandExecutor.java:124)
        at org.pentaho.di.kitchen.Kitchen.main(Kitchen.java:290)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Does somebody know to to fix it. Database connection, read and write permission everything is ok

Comment: What are you doing when the error es throwned? Is an specific step or just opening PDI? You are mentioning connection to a database, what type of database? Do you have the correct driver to connect to the database?